# What kind of punctuation should be used here?

Tags: punctuation

What type of punctuation should be used in the sentence "What is Stonehenge you might ask"?

Comment: I think that modern styles allow the quotes to be dropped for notional speech. What is Stonehenge? you might ask. The notional speech could be demarcated by italics: _What is Stonehenge?_ you might ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is correct. Usually such a sentence would be punctuated thusly.

So in this example: *'What is Stonehenge?', you might ask.*

Comment: I'm not averse to the use of double punctuation, but I don't think the comma serves a useful purpose here.